# Files.app - how to control which app opens when a file is tapped?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, filesystem

**iOS 14.1**

I'm using iCloud Drive to store files and shuttle things back and forth between my Mac and iPhone.

When I tap a file from Files.app on the phone, it immediately opens in a seemingly random app. There is no prompt saying "Open in XXXX?". There also seems to be no way to view or control these file associations, nor any long-press → "Open with..." type of action.

Anyone got any insight into this maddening behavior?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there has **NEVER** been a way to choose what app opens what file on iOS... maddening indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the app to open your file by long pressing your file. In the menu, tap the "share" option and then tap the app that you would like to open your file in.

[image: Long pressing on your file]

[image: shows a row of apps that you can open your file in]